# Is Android's ARGB_8888 Bitmap internal format always RGBA?

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I am trying to create a `Bitmap` in Android using the `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888` after I have received the bytes from an external source. As I understand the fastest way to set raw bytes in a `Bitmap` (without using `JNI`) is by using the `copyPixelsFromBuffer()` method, however the question arises regarding the correct order of the bytes in that buffer.

After some trial and error, and despite the fact that `Config.ARGB_8888` suggests a correct order of `ARGB` it seems that the internal format used by `Bitmap` is `RGBA`. You can test this behavior using the following method inside an `Activity` i.e. in `onCreate()` (I have tested it in Android 4.4.4, it is true that the method tests `copyPixelsToBuffer()` but according to my tests `copyPixelsFromBuffer()` behaves the same):

```
private void testBitmap() {
    // one pixel bitmap
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    // as per javadoc, the int value is in ARGB format, so A=0xFF, R=0x11, G=0x22, B=0x33
    bitmap.setPixel(0, 0, 0xFF112233);

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4);   // 4 bytes for the single pixel
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
    buffer.position(0);

    // prints "Bytes: 0x11 0x22 0x33 0xFF"  (RGBA)
    System.out.println(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "Bytes: %s %s %s %s",
            toHexString(buffer.get()),
            toHexString(buffer.get()),
            toHexString(buffer.get()),
            toHexString(buffer.get())
    ));
}

private static String toHexString(byte b) {
    return Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF).toUpperCase();
}
```

My question is: Is this internal format documented anywhere? If not, then how do we know if the above code won't break in future versions of Android? Or perhaps there is some other suggested approach to copy raw bytes in a `Bitmap`?

Comment: isn't it related to `ByteBuffer#order()` ? just wild guess...

Comment: @pskink No it isn't. The result is the same no matter the byte order of the buffer. And if it was a byte order issue, I would expect a different output i.e. `BGRA`. The formats I have mentioned differ only in the alpha channel

Comment: oh, indeed, i missed you got `RGBA`, and not  as you said `BGRA`, cannot you instead use `int[] arr = new int[1];
        bitmap.getPixels(arr, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        Log.d(TAG, "test: " + Integer.toHexString(arr[0]));` ?

Comment: @pskink I could probably do that, however I am interested in the case of bytes, because the javadocs mention that the copy operations involving buffers copy the data "as is" while the `getPixels()`/`setPixels()` convert the bytes to packed `int`s. I am looking for a way to avoid as much conversions as possible.

Comment: i see, it seems that it is just the way they named those `ARGB_*` constants, for ndk they are more precise: https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___bitmap.html#gaea286a2d4c61ae2abb02b51500499f13

Answer (score 4):

Thought I'd give an updated answer as I was recently confused by this.

The behavior when calling `setPixels()` vs `copyPixelsFromBuffer()` does reflect a difference in the way colors are represented in high-level APIs vs the actual internal ordering of bytes in the Bitmap. This is sort of documented in the Bitmap class (at least now), but not easy to parse through.

The more high-level interface with `setPixels()` expects ints as they are in other high-level interfaces like resources and with the Color class, so ARGB [as noted here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#setPixels(int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)). You can then do things like this easily: `bitmap.setPixel(0,0,Color.RED)`. The Color class mentions the ordering [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#encoding) as:

```
int color = (A & 0xff) << 24 | (R & 0xff) << 16 | (G & 0xff) << 8 | (B & 0xff);
```

The internal representation is RGBA though as you found out from`copyPixelsFromBuffer()`. It's sort of hinted at in the Bitmap.Config [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config#ARGB_8888) instead, as seen below, and also in the NDK Bitmap header which names it's enum ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888:

```
int color = (A & 0xff) << 24 | (B & 0xff) << 16 | (G & 0xff) << 8 | (R & 0xff);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the documentation:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

There are several usages of namely RGBA model.

For instance `pack(int color)` method. The specified ARGB color int to an RGBA color long in the sRGB color space.

You can try to find 'RGBA' word in the page I gave. Most of base concepts are used RGBA model.

Comment: thanks. I understand that `RGBA` may be commonly used, however I would feel more re-assured if I found something official specifically for the `Bitmap` class.