# Why is copyPixelsFromBuffer giving incorrect color? setPixels is correct but slow

Tags: android, performance, colors, bitmap, bytebuffer

For my android app I am getting a `ByteBuffer` from native code. It contains the pixel color values to create a bitmap.

Original image -

[image]

I used `copyPixelsFromBuffer` on bitmap, but I am getting incorrect color on displaying the bitmap.

Here is the code for this approach -

**Approach 1**

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ...

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
buffer.rewind();
bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
```

**Approx. time** -  ~0.4 ms
**Result** - Wrong colors -
[image]

**Approach 2**

Next I tried `setPixels`. It still gives wrong colors and is more than 10 times slower and uses extra memory for `int[]`. Please note that `buffer.hasArray()` is `false`, so I can't get array from buffer.

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ...

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
buffer.rewind();

int[] pixels = new int[width * height];

for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
    int a = buffer.get();
    int r = buffer.get();
    int g = buffer.get();
    int b = buffer.get();
    pixels[i] = a << 24 | r << 16 | g << 8 | b;
}
bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
```

**Approx. time** -  ~4.0 ms
**Result** - Wrong colors -

[image]

**Approach 3**

This time I used `setPixels` but with the pixel values taken from `IntBuffer` representation of `ByteBuffer`. The colors are correct but the time is still high and there is extra memory allocation.

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ...
IntBuffer intBuffer = buffer.asIntBuffer();

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
buffer.rewind();

int[] pixels = new int[width * height];

for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
    pixels[i] = intBuffer.get();
}
bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
```

**Approx. time** -  ~3.0 ms
**Result** - Correct colors -

[image]

Any hints on why I am getting wrong colors with `copyPixelsFromBuffer`? I want to use it instead of `setPixels` as it is faster and does not require extra memory allocation.

Comment: I suspect a color space problem, but I don't quite see how it can be given that your third attempt works correctly. It might be a nice experiment to use `bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer()` to create a new buffer from the results of approach 3, then check for differences between the two buffers. This might help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Just thought of something else: make sure your buffer's byte order is set to `ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN`. A mismatch there could cause weird color effects.

Comment: Thanks @TedHopp, the tip about comparing the buffer using `copyPixelsToBuffer()` was very helpful. I realized the issue - the buffer is ARGB but the bitmap expects RGBA.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! You should mark your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the problem - even though the `Bitmap.Config` is said to be `ARGB_8888`, it really is `RGBA`. I think it is a huge bug in android developer documentation and code.

The same issue has been noted in this question - [Is Android's ARGB_8888 Bitmap internal format always RGBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500726/is-androids-argb-8888-bitmap-internal-format-always-rgba)

And the ndk documentation correctly notes the format to be `ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888`

Solution is simple - create the buffer with RGBA format. Or on the java side switch the channels, something like below -

```
for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
    Byte a = buffer.get();
    Byte r = buffer.get();
    Byte g = buffer.get();
    Byte b = buffer.get();
    bufferCopy.put(r);
    bufferCopy.put(g);
    bufferCopy.put(b);
    bufferCopy.put(a);
}
```

This is not very efficient code, but gets the job done.

Answer (score 2):

The Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 documentation mentions, "Use this formula to pack into 32 bits:
int color = (A & 0xff) << 24 | (B & 0xff) << 16 | (G & 0xff) << 8 | (R & 0xff);". It calls for the color to be packed in ABGR_8888 format yet it is the ARGB_8888 format, and according this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500726/is-androids-argb-8888-bitmap-internal-format-always-rgba) is formally referred to as ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888 [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/bitmap#gaea286a2d4c61ae2abb02b51500499f13) (ABGR_8888 backwards). In any case, this Kotlin function will convert your colors for use in copyPixelsFromBuffer.

```
fun androidBitmapFormatRGBA8888(color: Int): Int {
    val a = (color shr 24) and 255
    val r = (color shr 16) and 255
    val g = (color shr 8) and 255
    val b = color and 255

    return (a shl 24) or (b shl 16) or (g shl 8) or r
}
```